# gnome-terminal won't open after ppa install

Tags: command-line, apt, gnome, ppa

I'm new to Linux (I just recently started dual-booting Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 11). I wanted to select all from the terminal (I found that enabling the legacy shortcut would only select a screens worth, not the entire output) and found a PPA fix (https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-terminal/issues/372) that mentioned rolling back to a prior VTE. However, I definitely should've looked a little closer because the PPA seemed to be regarding the `MATE terminal`, while I was working with `gnome-terminal`. Upon adding and installing from the PPA, `gnome-terminal` won't run (even AFTER removing the PPA). Here's what I've tried:

- Removing the PPA (via apt and `ppa-purge`)
- Running terminal via Ctrl+alt+T/applications menu/VS Code Integrated Terminal (hangs and eventually times out)
- Uninstalling and reinstalling gnome-terminal
- Sudo apt update/clean/upgrade/--fix-broken install
- Changing my language in settings (I saw this suggested, didn't seem to fix the issue)
- Shutting down my computer

I know there's other terminal options out there, but I would prefer to use the built-in gnome-terminal if possible. Any help you can provide is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You removed the PPA before purging it, which causing that `ppa-purge` not correctly downgrade all the installed packages.

The correct way you should do is just `sudo ppa-purge ppa:maintainer/name`, to get rid of the PPA and downgrade installed packages. Nothing else!

Now, to fix the issue, just re-install the stock versions of the packages via command (for 22.04):

`sudo apt install --reinstall gir1.2-vte-2.91=0.68.0-1 libvte-2.91-0=0.68.0-1 libvte-2.91-common=0.68.0-1`

Or, use **synaptic package manager** to search all packages installed from that PPA one by one, and use 'Package -> Force Version...' menu to downgrade to (select install) the old versions.